# NullPointerException because the Thread is null?

Tags: java, android

I received this stack strace three times now during the last months. It's only these three lines:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.myapp.rec.MyThread.void run()(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I wonder if this could mean that the method `MyThread.run` got `null`? Or are there other possible reasons for the `NullPointerException`?

The thread is started via

```
myThread = new Thread(new MyThread());
Rec.threadWritingShouldContinue = true;
myThread.start();
```

The source of the thread is about that:

```
class MyThread implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while ( Rec.threadWritingShouldContinue ) {
            int bufferSize;

            /* Do some stuff with local variables
               ...
             */
            try {
                MyMain.fileIDwrite.write(Rec.bigBuffer, Rec.bigBufByteWritePtr, bufferSize);
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                Rec.threadWritingShouldContinue = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling with debug information wont help as it can last weeks to see it again.

Comment: Without showing your code, this question cannot be answered

Comment: which part of the code? The call or the thread or both?

Comment: `de.myapp.rec.MyThread.void run()` <-- this is really a strange stacktrace entry... Is that a verbatim copy/paste?

Comment: Well, the code of `MyThread`; or don't you have it?

Comment: I got `de.myapp.rec.MyThread.void run()` by applying `retrace.sh` to the original stack trace and manually renamed `myapp` and `MyThread`.

Comment: It'd be more helpful if you posted the non transformed stacktrace. Now, the source...?

Comment: I have it, but I presumed that if the `NullPointerException` appeared in a specific line of the body of `MyThread` then the stack trace would contain an additional line?

Comment: Well, without code, can't tell ;) Also, can you compile with debug information so that you don't get that `Unknown source` stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if this could mean that the method MyThread.run is null?

No. Methods cannot be null.

> Or are there other possible reasons for the NullPointerException?

There is only one possible reason. The code dereferenced a null pointer.

Comment: Can methods become `null` if Android decides due to lack of memory to throw an app, whose threads are running but which is invisible, out of the main memory?

Comment: @HartmutPfitzinger Methods can't become anything, let alone null. You're barking up the wrong tree completely. I cannot understand what the mystery is here. You have the source code. Any Java programmer should be able to debug a NullPointerException. The meaning of the stack trace, even after you mangled it for some reason, is that the exception happened *inside* that method.

Comment: It is very helpful information that I was "barking up the wrong tree". I only was wondering why there wasn't an additional line in the stack trace pointing to the source line of `MyThread` where the Exception appeared. Actually, I didn't "mangle" the trace, I only removed the obfuscation via `retrace.sh` which changed only the 2nd line from `at de.myapp.rec.ec.run(Unknown Source)` to `at de.myapp.rec.MyThread.void run()(Unknown Source)`.

Comment: Your comment brought me forward. I discovered that `MyMain.fileIDwrite` is set to `null` somewhere else (possibly while the thread is still running). And since `null` doesn't have any method, `MyMain.fileIDwrite.write` would not leave a line in the stack trace, would it? Am I possibly barking the right tree?

Comment: 'Since null does not have any method' is meaningless, and so therefore is any conclusion you may try to derive from it, including that one. The write() method you refer to hasn't been called, because the NPE occurred first, so of course it doesn't appear in the stack trace. Is that what you mean? You have a very strange way of expressing yourself.

Comment: If this case would have been clear to me I wont ask, so thanks for teaching. I learn.